# not printing after "if not" instruction in python

Tags: python, loops, printing

< I have the following code:

```
print("Options:")
print("Option 1")
print("Option 2")
print("Option 3")
print("Option 4")
choice = int(input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? "))
while choice not in ['1','2','3','4']:
    choice = int(input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? "))
    if not choice:
        print: ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. ")
```

> However, the output when running the module is:
>
> What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]?
>   5
>   What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]?
>
> I want this to loop until 1,2,3, or 4 is selected & produce the following output:
>
> What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? 7
>   Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4.
>
> What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]?
>
> Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The shown code isn't properly indented, please repair.

Comment: @chepner  - you were on the case too quick (impressive) - I was still proofreading!  Have amended.

Answer (score 2):

`if not choice:` is equivalent to `if choice == 0:` in this context, since you will only reach that statement after `input` has returned and `int` hasn't raised an exception.

Use the following idiom for a potentially infinite loop that doesn't duplicate the call to `input`:

```
...
print("Option 4")
while True:
    choice = int(input("..."))
    if choice in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        break
    print("Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon after the line `print: ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. ")` might be causing the string to not be printed. I don't know why that doesn't cause a syntax error though.

A pretty rudimentary solution.

```python
print("Options:")
print("Option 1")
print("Option 2")
print("Option 3")
print("Option 4")

choice = "0"
while choice not in ['1','2','3','4']:
    choice = input("What would you like to choose [1,2,3,4]? ")
    if choice not in ['1', '2', '3', '4']:
        print ("Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4. ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsIwEEX3OcUnm1YIYpKCIIhH0J2L0kWpkQZLprQppaePiYgi9cNsHjP/Tb/4lpwOoR@s8zk/996SGw98w34I5IqoFdErUkTCmpZsY3AE33E2t7YzeCNHHtahzGQmMhVHxymy6sAQ87mzrp9i57WtPWaauhsWmtDZh4GntEajQSmFEloU1QlRmu7t/Z8HSYRkwleV8vocOb90po59xnkzQAooAQ0aUGxjcQh7Jp8)